# How to use an mp4 video stored on Dropbox within an Alexa Skill that uses an ALP document

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

My goal is to get an mp4 video i placed in dropbox to work within my Alexa Skill in which I am using an ALP document to include multimedia support.  I am not interested in using Amazon S3 storage.

I was following [a tutorial by dabbelab](https://dabblelab.com/templates/5-alexa-video-example-skill).

I could get their video to work: https://player.vimeo.com/external/373749691.hd.mp4?s=e43554c91fc796a20f051dcb8b45a74d035a6daa&profile_id=174

I could not get an mp4 video in my drop box to work:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/i8g0j8ghzprqyp3/Baby%20Cats%20-%20Cute%20and%20Funny%20Baby%20Cat%20Videos%20Compilation.mp4?dl=0

From what I can determine through Amazon's doc, I should be able to use any mp4 as long as I am using https.  It is unclear to me what it is I am missing.  Any advice greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I'm seeing is the link. It ends with "dl=0." That link opens a dropbox page for playing the video, not the video itself.

Change that to "raw=1" and you should get the video itself like APL needs, not an HTML page.